# How to use Roboto font with android support library 23?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am migrating my application to android support library 23.1.
One of the things I noticed, that there is no roboto font for my text widgets.
I have done a search through support library project and could not find no reference to roboto font. Neither is it among assets.
I would like to know how could I include roboto font in my project and use it.
I want to use this font in styles.
I have found some quasi "tips" like this

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontName);
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

But this is totally unaceptably. All the theming is thrown out of window, font must be hardcoded in quasillion of places. It is a no go. I have seen library that managed this, so I wonder why is google not capable of doing this.
So: How to include and corectly use roboto font (or any other for that matter) in my project?

Comment: Did you add the font to your Assets folder?

Comment: Yes. Does it make it automagically available as any other built in font?

Comment: No, you need to manually set fonts you've added. Are you sure the value of fontName is correct?

Comment: If you are willing to use library, I can show you a good library where you can add all the font required and simply mention them in style.xml and strings.xml. [Fontify](https://github.com/danh32/Fontify)

Comment: This one is also recommended, though not answering the question
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: @Fontify Well. you could. I would still rather see how this os done.I am not inclined to libraries as they are not maintained and one might end up stuck with outdated library and the original problem.

Comment: @UdiIdan How does one manually set fonts that I added?